# Parton Distribution Functions - Antiquarks?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, antimatter, quarks, partons

In all the PDF plots that I have seen so far (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5452  Fig. $3$ and $4$) the PDFs for sea or charm quarks contained only the strange or charm quark, but not the $\bar{s}$ or $\bar{c}$ quark. Since the sea quarks can only be created through the process $g\rightarrow c\bar{c}$ or $g\rightarrow s\bar{s}$, I was left wondering why that is the case?

Comment: They are identical to those of their quark, for normal target hadrons, no?

Comment: In the first sentence, did you mean to write "the PDFs for **strange** or charm quarks contained only the strange or charm quark"?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as Mr. Zachos said, if the hadron has no valence strange or charm (or top or bottom) quarks, then the quark and antiquark distributions will be identical by the reasoning you gave (that they only ever come in pairs).

For example, a proton has a valence structure of $|uud\rangle$. Therefore for the strange quark we'd have$f_{s/P}(x)=f_{\bar s / P}(x)$, and likewise for all the other heavy quarks.